# JS Div tag is not hiding with if and else statements

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, tags

```
function nes(){
    if (document.getElementById('nes').style.display == 'block'){
      document.getElementById('nes').style.display = 'none';
    }

    else if (document.getElementById('snes').style.display == 'block') {
      document.getElementById('snes').style.display = 'none';
    }

    else if (document.getElementById('gba').style.display == 'block') {
      document.getElementById('gba').style.display = 'none';
    }

    else if (document.getElementById('sega').style.display == 'block') {
      document.getElementById('sega').style.display = 'none';
    }

    else if (document.getElementById('flash').style.display == 'block') {
      document.getElementById('flash').style.display = 'none';
    }

    else if (document.getElementById('n64').style.display == 'block') {
      document.getElementById('n64').style.display = 'none';
    }

    else if (document.getElementById('all').style.display == 'block') {
      document.getElementById('all').style.display = 'none';
    }

    document.getElementById('snes').style.display = 'block';

  }

  <input id=nesdot type="image" src="C:\Users\Me\Documents\Website\Assets\Home Page\selection dot.png", onclick='nes()'/>

  <div id=nes>
    <input type="image" src="C:\Users\Sam Scolari\Documents\Totally Not An Arcade\Assets\Home Page\Adjusted Logos\NES.png"/>
  </div>

  <div id=all>
    <input type="image" src="C:\Users\Sam Scolari\Documents\Totally Not An Arcade\Assets\Home Page\Adjusted Logos\A2Z.png"/>
  </div>
```

I am trying to replace a picture that is in a div tag with javascript. When I click the button it seems to skip over all of the if and else statements and goes right to the single command at the end of the function. Is there something wrong with the syntax of the statements? It outputs to my website by adding the next image directly under the one that was supposed to be replaced. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Your id attributes should probably have quotes around them: ```<input id="nesdot"/>```

Comment: The DIVs don't have any `style` attribute, so `document.getElementById('nes').style.display` will return an empty string, not `block`. You need to use `getComputedStyle` to get the actual style.

Comment: would --- document.getElementById('nes').getComputedStyle.display = 'block'; --- work?

Comment: thanks guys. fixed it by adding the display style to the actual tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this code:

```
function nes(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('nes');
    var displayStyleNes = null;
    if (elem.style.display) {
        displayStyleNes = elem.style.display;
    } else if (elem.currentStyle) {
        displayStyleNes = elem.currentStyle.display;
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    displayStyleNes = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("display");

    if (displayStyleNes === 'block'){
        document.getElementById('nes').style.display = 'none';
    }
    //.....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IDs in HTML need quotes to be effective. The inspector won't prompt you any errors but the IDs will not be affected.

```
<input id="snes"/>
```

I assume that your function is wrapped in a script normally? If not, that is another problem!

Hope this helps :)